# Append new rows based on cell values across multiple columns

Tags: python, excel

I would like to create a new table where selected columns combined in one column then append new rows based on the cell value across the selected columns for example,

| ID | Jan | Feb |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | Doing | Completed |
| 12 | Completed | - |
| 13 | - | Completed |
| 14 | Doing | Doing |

I want to convert the above table into this table below

| ID | Status |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | Doing |
| 11 | Completed |
| 12 | Completed |
| 13 | Completed |
| 14 | Doing |
| 14 | Doing |

I would be thankful if anyone can help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

If your table is a list of lists, for each element of a column you want to merge, create a new row and append it.

This function I made takes as arguments the table you want to treat, the new header of this table (must be a list) and the columns you want to merge and in the order you want to merge them.

```
def mergeCols(table, new_header, *cols):
    new_table = [new_header]
    for row in table[1:]:
        for idx in cols:
            if row[idx] != '-':
                new_row = [None if i in cols else row[i] for i in range(len(row))]
                new_row[cols[0]] = row[idx]
                new_row = [new_row[i] for i in range(len(new_row)) if i not in cols[1:]]
                new_table.append(new_row)
    return new_table
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out one solution in Power Query

1st - Merge the selected columns by clicking **Merge Columns**, choose comma as the separator. Name the column as Status.

2nd - Select the merged column (Status) then click **Split column** choose by delimiter. Choose comma as the delimiter. Split at choose **Each occurence of the delimiter** click **Advanced options** and choose **rows**